# Can an RTOS (real-time operating system) read and write files in a filesystem?

Tags: memory, operating-systems, memory-management, real-time

Can an RTOS (real-time operating system) read and write files in a filesystem? Or is it restricted to operating with volatile memory (RAM) only?

- If it can, how can the timing guarantees be enforced?
- If it can, does it need a special type of filesystem or can it work with standard non-volatile memories such as an USB Flash Drive?
- If it can't, how can a program executing within an RTOS save data in a non-volatile way? (for example, save the result of complex computation in order to use it days later when it is turned on again)

Comment: Are these homework questions?

Comment: *"Can an RTOS (real-time operating system) read and write files in a filesystem?"* -- Yes.

Comment: @Ramhound Haha, absolutely not. My research on the topic of RTOS yielded lots of information on how RAM works within them, with different protection mechanisms (or none at all), but there was no particular mention about filesystems. I was wondering if it was (1) because of course they can work with them normally, nothing special, not even worth mentioning or (2) they are usually turned on all the time while used in embedded systems performing real-time computations and transmitting data that filesystems aren't even used anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows CE and QNX 4 are examples of real-time operating systems, and they both have filesystems, so it has been done.

Where it really matters: A system builder will design a system and include an RTOS as part of that system, will design things so the RTOS doesn't get overloaded, and make it a closed system so unexpected loads can't happen.

So: writes to storage in an RTOS in something like a car will probably be planned, expected, and scheduled properly as to leave bandwidth for other tasks--specifically designed not to overload the CPU--and you can't mess this up by installing arbitrary programs.

Storage tasks aren't technically "real time" even on a non-RTOS system most of the time.  Reads and writes are cached in RAM and then written to disk when the operating system determines it's a good idea.  It's one reason why you have to shutdown your computer cleanly and not just turn it off.

This is why RTOS's aren't in the same category as general-purpose operating systems.

Comment: Thanks! So it can be done, but isn't very common, right? Am I correct in my impression that applications that need to run inside an RTOS probably don't have a need for storing data in a non-volatile memory anyway?

Comment: Can't make that assumption.  Medical devices for example probably need to log data and at the same time react to sensor data in real time.